# Kendo mobile indexedlistview not working on Icenium

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

i tried the basic example hosted on kendo mobile github:https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-plugins/tree/master/Mobile/IndexedListView

On local, works fine.

But i cant make it work on Icenium. I already ask them, but they recommend to ask around.

Kendo Music Store use this pluguin and works and i dont understand the difference.

Here the icenium proyect:
https://github.com/andrescolodrero/iceniumIndexedLIstView

Error:
:"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_scroller' "

Answer (score 0):

IndexedListView is not yet updated to work with the latest Kendo UI Mobile (Q2 2013 and later). We plan to update it in the coming weeks.

Comment: Thanks,for the answer. For now it works only on Kendo UI Complete v2013.1.621.

Comment: I just check the example in Kendo Music Store. The widget doesnt work fine. After scroll, i navigated to another view, come back to the indexed listview, and the widget behave very weird.

Answer (score 0):

The private method '_scroller' is now public 'scroller', changing this in the demo code would address that particular error, but there are other problems with the demo with Kendo UI Q2 2013. We're in the process of updating the demo and would ping back here, whenever it is done.

Comment: Thank.i finally get the "indexedlistview" css and i created my own "indexedlistview" but not reading all the items of the datasource, because im using a big datasource and fail in some devices. But i will check the widget again once is complete.